# Why is my htaccess 301 redirect not working?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an htaccess file in the root folder of my website that redirects a webpage like so:

```
Redirect 301 /products/?id=63207354 /product/63
```

I want the page "mydomain.com/products/?id=63207354" to go to "mydomain.com/product/63".

It doesn't work. Any idea why?

If I put garbage in the htaccess file then I get a server error so I know the file is being read. It just doesn't redirect.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect` directive. You'll need to use mod_rewrite and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=63207354$
RewriteRule ^products/?$ /product/63? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Lin. Your solution takes me to "/product/63?id=63207354". How would I make it go just "/product/63"

Comment: @Andrew sorry, forgot a `?`